# Autossh script running as systemctl start SERVICE works but systemctl enable SERVICE failed

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, systemd, systemctl, autossh

We are trying to get autossh to connect to remote server at boot time in Ubuntu 16.04.2. So we use systemctl to do the job. The script is as following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Keeps a tunnel to 'remote server' open
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/autossh -NR 83232:localhost:22 -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa REMOTE_USER@REMOTE_IP

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It would work fine if we start the service by using start

```
systemctl start SERVICE
```

But it would fail if we use enable service

```
systemctl enable SERVICE
```

The error code is

> “ssh: connect to host REMOTE_IP port 22: Network is unreachable”

Can anybody offer any advices?

Many thanks.

Comment: Most probably network is not ready yet when you start the service.

Comment: This solved the problem. Many thanks! @Jakuje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `After=network.target`, use `After=network-online.target`.

More about systemd network targets are documented on the [systemd wiki page](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/).