# systemd service fails to activate

Tags: service, installation, startup, systemd

I am working to create a service that triggers a script upon boot. The script then installs and activates a piece software. I only want this service to run once so that it installs the software on initial boot. This is being built into an AMI for standard deployment in an enterprise.

I currently have the following:

`/etc/systemd/system/startup.service` (executable using chmod +x; enabled using "systemctl enable startup.service")

`/var/tmp/LinuxDeploymentScript.sh`

The service contains:

```
[Unit]
After=remote-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
ExecStart=/var/tmp/LinuxDeploymentScript.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I test the service by using `systemctl start startup.service` it runs successfully, but when I leave it enabled and reboot the system, it fails to activate:

[Screenshot of failure log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByQJ9.png)

Any help would be great. I have a thought that it could be my `After=` setting may not be far enough into the computer spinning up to be successful.

Comment: maybe your script tries to download from external sources, but network is not yet loaded correctly. you could modify your deploy script with checking the external source and leave a note in journal if not able to connect.

Comment: you may want to check here if your deploy script needs networking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805354/systemd-start-service-at-boot-time-after-network-is-really-up-for-wol-purpose

Comment: I think you are both right. I changed the `After=` to `network.target` and that seemed to do the trick!